# Java org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text typing has a -huge- delay

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Code:

```
        Display display = new Display();
        RowLayout rowLayout = new RowLayout();

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(rowLayout);

        Text textArea = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        textArea.setLayoutData(new RowData(200, 200));


        shell.open();
        while(!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if(display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        display.dispose();
```

Problem: Typing in text is dog slow. I literally have to wait 1 - 3 seconds to let the text widget lag behind displaying my text in snail steps. Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: One thing - your `readAndDispatch` loop is backwards - it returns `false` if there's nothing else to do (and you should `sleep()`).  `sleep()` *should* be pretty efficient in waking, but this could be the culprit.

Comment: @EdwardThomson THANK YOU :), it was indeed the loop. Please make a seperate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `readAndDispatch` loop is backwards.  The [documentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html&ei=G-RsT96DBuzPiAKo3-CGBQ&usg=AFQjCNFXslppe30-Qd2YVUU0icJ1X2wcnQ) for `Display#readAndDispatch()` states that it:

> returns `true` if there is potentially more work to do, or `false` if the caller can sleep until another event is placed on the event queue.

Thus, your loop should actually be:

```
while(! shell.isDisposed())
{
    if(! display.readAndDispatch())
    {
        display.sleep();
    }
}
```

My understanding of `sleep()` was that it *should* be fairly efficient about waking up when there's a new event to service, but that's certainly not a guarantee.